# XCode & Facebook IOS SDK - Instructions incorrect

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, sdk

I am following this guide.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

For setting up the Facebook IOS SDK for my XCode project..

I got to the part that says to run

```
% ~/facebook-ios-sdk/scripts/build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh
```

in the terminal..

I tried that and it didn't work, so i went to find that script file manually and it isn't in the folder specified.. My questions is am i missing something? or does anyone know if the file was renamed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this script is not included in the newest version on [github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/scripts).

However you can download the [SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/downloads/) and use it as described in the ["Getting Started" section - Start a new Xcode Project](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/getting-started-with-the-ios-sdk/#project). So far I had no issues with the SDK 3.0 and ARC in my project.

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out, i used a bunch of different tutorials and pieced it together.

Comment: Though my answer is just three lines, it took at least four days for me testing and struggling with different tools, facebook SDKs and tutorials until I found this solution to be the best one for my project. :-)

Answer (score 0):

That script is there in my instance. Is it possible that the facebook-ios-sdk directory isn't in the top level of your home directory as in /Users/yourusername/facebook-ios-sdk? It needs to be there for you to follow the instructions verbatim.